# MongoDb update object in a array on first occurence from last

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a sample document like shown below

```
{
 "_id" : "docID",
 "ARRAY" : [ 
    {
        "k" : "value",
        "T" : "20:15:35",
        "I" : "Hai"
    }, 
    {
        "K" : "some value",
        "T" : "20:16:35",
        "I" : "Hello"
    }, 
    {
        "K" : "some other value",
        "T" : "20:15:35",
        "I" : "Update"
    } 
   ]
}
```

I am trying to update the last element in the "ARRAY" based on field **"ARRAY.T"**(which is only field i know at the point of update), but what my problem is first element in the array matches the query and its **ARRAY.I** field is updated.

***Query used to update:***

```
db.collection.update( { _id: "docID","ARRAY.T" : "20:15:35"},
                { $set: { "ARRAY.$.I": "Updated value" }               
                })
```

Actually i don't know index of the array where to update so i have to use **ARRAY.I** in the query, is there any way to to tell Mongodb to update the first element matched the query from last of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you are saying in that you want to match the last element in this case or in  fact process the match in reverse order. There is no way to modify this and the index stored in the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator will always be the "first" match.

But you can change your approach to this, as the default behavior of [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) is to "append" to the end of the array. But MongoDB 2.6 introduced a [**`$position`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) modifier so you can in fact always "pre-pend" to the array meaning your "oldest" item is at the end.

Take this for example:

```js
db.artest.update(
   { "array": { "$in": [5] } },
   { "$push": { "array": { "$each": [5], "$position": 0 } }},
   { "upsert": true }
)

db.artest.update(
    { "array": { "$in": [5] } },
    { "$push": { "array": { "$each": [6], "$position": 0 } }},
    { "upsert": true }
)
```

This results in a document that is the "reverse" of the normal `$push` behavior:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53eaf4517d0dc314962c93f4"), "array" : [ 6, 5 ] }
```

Alternately you could apply the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier when updating your documents in order to "order" the elements so they were reversed. But that may not be the best option if duplicate values are stored.

So look into storing your arrays in "reverse" if you intend to match the "newest" items "first". Currently that is your only way of getting your "match from last" behavior.

Comment: thanks for the idea @neil, currently i fulfilled my need by updating using INDEX, which i get through aggregation(i need rarely)